# Why am I not receiving firebase messages?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I see my server is sending correctly the messages to firebase API since it returns a **success: 1** response but my client is not receiving the messages, what is happening, my code is:

```
  const messaging = firebase.messaging()
  const that = this

  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
    return messaging.getToken()
  })
  .then(function(token) {
    that.updateServerFirebaseToken(token)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })

  // Call to user
  messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('firebase', payload)
    if(payload.data.status == 'calling') {
      this.audio.play()
      this.$store.commit(types.CALLING, JSON.decode(payload.data.order))
    }
  })
```

and my service worker `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('FIREBASE call', payload);
  if(payload.data.status == 'calling') {
    channel.postMessage(payload.data)

    return self.registration.showNotification('Nuevo pedido', {body: "Llamada para transporte de un pedido"})
  }
})
```

Comment: Having the same problem since yesterday, suddenly my SW isn't receiving any of the messages I send even though I get a success: 1 response.

Comment: Yeah that happened yesterday, my code was working fine suddenly it stopped to receive messages.

Comment: I reached out to firebase support. They replied that is indeed an issue that more people are having. They're looking into it.. it started working just now so hopefully they fixed it

Comment: Issue has been fixed. any explanation with the issue.

Comment: If you want a more stable and solid push notification system **DON'T  use Firebase**, many problems including that messages sometimes can take **several minutes** to arrive, I'm using pushy.me and works fine and cheap.

Comment: I got the same problem. Successful response from the server, but the chrome doesn't response. I test it on the localhost. Any help?

Comment: I'm having same problem, same code working at local but when it is deployed to azure client not getting the notification. it is so frustrating. any solution?